# Sharepoint 2013 - Global Navigation, Creating Explicit Inclusion Site Collections

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, term-store, global-navigation

I followed Benny Skogberg's instructions for creating an [Explicit Inclusion Site Collection for Global Navigation here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/106086/sharepoint-2013-global-navigation-across-site-collections). Everything worked for me through the creation of the 'Reuse terms from the Site Collection navigation' /About Us page.

I saw the local site collection term group and used it to recreate the global nav links on that single collection. The problem came when I tried to apply this logic to the other site collections I had created. When I go to any other site collection then choose site settings/term store management I do not see the local Site Collection Term Group.

Any idea why this might happen?

What I am seeing on About Us:

[image]

What I am seeing on all the other site collections:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You may need to recreate the Term Set again. Navigate to http://portal/services/_layouts/15/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx directly or navigate through Site Settings:

[image]

Make sure you have selected Managed Navigation radio button.

Click on Create Term Set and check if that solves the problem.

Here is my view from the Services AreaNavigationSettings page:

[image]
[image]