# Moving navigation items from one site collection to another site collection

Tags: master-page, navigation

I have created the vertical navigation items by adding heading and link using **structural navigation: Editing and Sorting** (in Site Settings -> navigation). I have created the design package of the site collection and imported into another site collection, the themes get applied successfully but I think creating design package not includes the navigation items. So, How to achieve this?

Comment: Take a look at this : http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/106086/sharepoint-2013-global-navigation-across-site-collections It has the functionality to achieve cross site collection navigation. May be this will help you.